# Saving database values as variables

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I can't figure out how to save individual data from an Access database into variables.

I understand that you can save variables like this:

```
int memberID;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MemberDetails WHERE [MemberID] =@MemberID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", memberID);

try
{
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        lblName.Text = (memberID);
    }
  con.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

However I want to save all the data into separate variables, something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [MemberID] = @MemberID, [Name] = @Name, [Surname] = @Surname";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", memberID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", surname);
```

This obviously doesn't work (otherwise I wouldn't be here) but is anything like this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is not a valid sql as far as I know. You are literaly filtering your column which belongs on `where` part. Can you please be more specific about what you try to do exactly? Are you try to `INSERT` these values?

Comment: Exactly, any idea on how I would go about saving the data as variables?

Comment: You're missing a DataReader where you see the results of your query and assign each variable the value from the database.  You aren't showing the executing the query code.

Comment: "save variables"... you don't seem to be "saving" anything here.

Comment: `lblName.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString();`

Comment: Your first example is not correct. `memberID` is part of the *input* into the `SELECT` statement and you are not getting any information from the `SELECT` statement at all. In your second example, your `SELECT` syntax does not make any sense. Are you trying to *get* those columns from the table into variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this great tutorial from Microsoft, it explains on how to query an MS Access database with C# and how to process the results: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx

What you could do to achieve the desired result is something like this (this is a slightly modified example from the article mentioned above):

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
OleDbDataReader reader = null;
try
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
        "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("MyDataFolder/MyAccessDb.mdb"));
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = 
        new OleDbCommand("Select MemberID, Name, Surname FROM MemberDetails WHERE MemberID = @MemberID", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", memberID);

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        memberID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MemberID"));
        name = reader["Name"].ToString();
        surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
    }

}
finally
{
    if (reader != null)  reader.Close();
    if (conn != null)  conn.Close();
}
```

Be carefull though, this will only work correctly when there is only one result returned in be the database query. When multiple records are returned only the last will be stored in the variables.

When you need to capture multiple results you will probably want to create a Member class, create an instance for each record and add the instance to a members list. Something like this:

```
    public class Member
    {
        public int MemberId {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Surname {get; set;}
    }

public IList<Member> GetMembers()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = null;
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("MyDataFolder/MyAccessDb.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = 
            new OleDbCommand("Select MemberID, Name, Surname FROM MemberDetails", conn);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var members = new List<Member>();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            var member = new Member();
            member.MemberID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MemberID"));
            member.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            member.Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();

            members.Add(member);
        }

        return members;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)  reader.Close();
        if (conn != null)  conn.Close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks as though you're attempting to retrieve a row where you have a known `MemberID`.  If that's the case, then you can always do something like this

```
int memberID = [some number];
DataTable results = new DataTable(); //Your SQL row will be "saved" in here
string command = string.Format("select * from MemberDetails where MemberID = {0}", memberID);

using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command, con))
{
    sda.Fill(results); //Your DataTable now has your values
}
```

All you need is something where you can feed the `memberID` to your condition variable.